# How can I import 22.000 products to Magento with a single blow?

Tags: php, sql, ruby, magento

I'm working on a Magento store and I'm looking to import 22.000 products with a single solution.

I've written a Ruby wrapper for the REST API, it takes around 7 seconds to create a single product (visible in store, assigned to a product category, assigned to website and with one image)

The Ruby wrapper for the REST API is tested against a demo Magento store hosted on a DigitalOcean VPS with 2 CPU'S and 2GB RAM.

It would take a very long time to import the 22.000 with a single solution using the Ruby wrapper.

Since I'm not a very experienced programmer and don't have PHP or SQL knowledge, I'm wondering how a more experienced programmer would solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to check out this site `http://gauss-development.com/blog/magento-mass-product-import/` since I'm pretty sure this is what you need !

They have API called Datapump and it can import up to 14 items per second.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried MAGMI? http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

According to me it is the fastest way to import products! It is also very scalable and flexible. It provides you a lot of possibilities to extends its default functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you could do something like

```
CREATE TABLE db2.table LIKE db1.table;
INSERT INTO db2.table SELECT * FROM db1.table;
```

Comment: True. But not the question the OP was asking.